# Safari 11.0.1: 3d transform bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I am working on an opening cube with CSS3 3d transform, and it's working fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
However, in Safari, the cube is moving to a weird place for some reason.

```js
let isExpanded = false;
let cube = document.querySelector(".cube");

document.querySelector("#toggle").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector("#toggle").disabled = true;
  toggle();
}

function toggle() {
  if (!isExpanded) {
    isExpanded = true;
    // Pause Rotation
    document.querySelector(".cube").classList.add("pause");
    // Open Cube
    open();
  } else {
    isExpanded = false;
    close();
  }
}

function close() {
  // Close the cube
  cube.classList.remove("open");
  cube.style.bottom = "0";
  // Rotate to the start position and restart animation
  setTimeout(function() {
    cube.classList.remove("origin-bottom");
  }, 1000); // >= side transform's transition time
  setTimeout(function() {
    cube.style.animation = "spin 15s infinite linear";
    cube.style.webkitAnimation = "spin 15s infinite linear";
    document.querySelector("#toggle").disabled = false;
  }, 1200);
}

function open() {
  // Set transform value to current position & Disable Animation
  prop = window.getComputedStyle(cube, null).getPropertyValue("transform");
  cube.style.transform = prop;
  cube.style.webkitTransform = prop;
  cube.style.MozTransform = prop;
  cube.style.msTransform = prop;
  cube.style.OTransform = prop;
  cube.style.animation = "none";
  cube.style.webkitAnimation = "none";
  // Rotate the cube to its initial position & Remove pause
  setTimeout(function() {
    cube.classList.remove("pause");
    cube.classList.add("origin-bottom");
    cube.style.transform = "rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(42deg)";
    cube.style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(42deg)";
    cube.style.MozTransform = "rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(42deg)";
    cube.style.msTransform = "rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(42deg)";
    cube.style.OTransform = "rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(42deg)";
  }, 50);
  // Open the cube
  setTimeout(function() {
    cube.classList.add("open");
    document.querySelector("#toggle").disabled = false;
  }, 1000); // >= side transform's transition time
}
```

```css
body {background: #333;}
.cube-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.cube-wrapper .cube {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  animation: spin 15s infinite linear;
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .side {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, background 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .right {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .left {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .front {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .behind {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
/* pause */
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.pause, .preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important;
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
/* open */
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.open .right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px) !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.open .left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px) !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.open .front {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px) !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.open .behind {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px) !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.origin-bottom .right {
  transform-origin: bottom !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.origin-bottom .left {
  transform-origin: bottom !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.origin-bottom .top {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.origin-bottom .front {
  transform-origin: bottom !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.origin-bottom .behind {
  transform-origin: bottom !important;
}
/* animation */
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(42deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(340deg) rotateY(382deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
<div class="preserve3d">
  <div class="cube-wrapper">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="side right">Right
      </div>
      <div class="side left">Left
      </div>
      <div class="side top">Top
      </div>
      <div class="side bottom">Bottom
      </div>
      <div class="side front">Front
      </div>
      <div class="side behind">Behind
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Though it is moved to a weird position, **the inspector is saying that it is in a correct place**. **Using** `getComputedStyle` **also gives the correct value**, so I don't know how to debug this problem.

I searched and found out that Safari has some issues with rotateY and tried the given solution, giving z-index value, but didn't work.

Here is the shortened version of code: https://jsfiddle.net/7mxghcq9/

Thank u in advance :)

Comment: do not rotate more then 179deg for safari,, very old bug apparently, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186768/safari-css-bug-animation-rotation-direction-incorrect

Comment: @KresimirPendic Isn't that an old bug that is solved in version 11.0.1? Anyway, I removed all the rotate value above 179deg but still has the same issue : https://jsfiddle.net/7mxghcq9/2/

Comment: @KresimirPendic caniuse does not report such an issue with Safari.

Comment: @jyoon You are required to post your code here, not a jsfiddle: [mcve]

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I was using jsfiddle because code snippet didn't seem to have SCSS compiler. But I attached the code with compiled CSS and cleaned them up as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I can't really say for sure what happens, nor if Safari is entirely wrong in its behavior...

Anyway, a working solution is to move the `cube.style.animation = 'none';` inside your first timeout, then to trigger a reflow before removing its paused status.

```js
function open() {
  // Set transform value to current position
  prop = window.getComputedStyle(cube, null).getPropertyValue("transform");

  cube.style.transform = prop;
  cube.style.webkitTransform = prop;
  cube.style.MozTransform = prop;
  cube.style.msTransform = prop;
  cube.style.OTransform = prop;
  
  // Disable Animation & Rotate the cube to its initial position & Remove pause
  setTimeout(function() {
    cube.style.animation = "none";
    cube.offsetWidth; // force a reflow
    cube.classList.remove("pause");
    cube.classList.add("origin-bottom");
    cube.style.transform = "rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(42deg)";
  }, 50);
  // Open the cube
  setTimeout(function() {
    cube.classList.add("open");
    document.querySelector("#toggle").disabled = false;
  }, 1000); // >= side transform's transition time
}

let isExpanded = false;
let cube = document.querySelector(".cube");

document.querySelector("#toggle").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector("#toggle").disabled = true;
  toggle();
}

function toggle() {
  if (!isExpanded) {
    isExpanded = true;
    // Pause Rotation
    document.querySelector(".cube").classList.add("pause");
    // Open Cube
    open();
  } else {
    isExpanded = false;
    close();
  }
}

function close() {
  // Close the cube
  cube.classList.remove("open");
  cube.style.bottom = "0";
  // Rotate to the start position and restart animation
  setTimeout(function() {
    cube.classList.remove("origin-bottom");
  }, 1000); // >= side transform's transition time
  setTimeout(function() {
    cube.style.animation = "spin 15s infinite linear";
    cube.style.webkitAnimation = "spin 15s infinite linear";
    document.querySelector("#toggle").disabled = false;
  }, 1200);
}
```

```css
body {background: #333;}
.cube-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.cube-wrapper .cube {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  animation: spin 15s infinite linear;
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .side {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, background 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .right {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .left {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .front {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube-wrapper .cube .behind {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
/* pause */
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.pause, .preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important;
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
/* open */
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.open .right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px) !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.open .left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px) !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.open .front {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px) !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.open .behind {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px) !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.origin-bottom .right {
  transform-origin: bottom !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.origin-bottom .left {
  transform-origin: bottom !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.origin-bottom .top {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.origin-bottom .front {
  transform-origin: bottom !important;
}
.preserve3d .cube-wrapper .cube.origin-bottom .behind {
  transform-origin: bottom !important;
}
.cube.origin-bottom{
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
/* animation */
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(42deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(340deg) rotateY(382deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
<div class="preserve3d">
  <div class="cube-wrapper">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="side right">Right
      </div>
      <div class="side left">Left
      </div>
      <div class="side top">Top
      </div>
      <div class="side bottom">Bottom
      </div>
      <div class="side front">Front
      </div>
      <div class="side behind">Behind
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I figured out that it works without pausing but guess your solution is better! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Clear history and try reloading the page. This happened to me too and clearing cache worked fine. You can rotate fully providing it’s safari 9. You’re using webkit so it should be good. Tested it myself and works fine for me

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. But unfortunately I emptied the full history and cache but didn't work for me :) Thanks anyway!