# CSS Animation doesn't take place

Tags: html, css, vue.js, css-animations

I'm trying to create a loading spinner. The styling of the spinner appears accordingly, however the animation doesn't take place and I'm really struggling to see what's wrong with this. I implemented this in a vue 3 project. Can anyone suggest any possible issue that might be causing this problem, please?

```html
<div v-if="isLoading" class="spinner"></div>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.spinner {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 4rem;
    width: 4rem;
    border: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-top-color: #C8D200;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: rotation 0.6s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: rotation 0.6s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: rotation 0.6s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: rotation 0.6s infinite linear;
    }

    @keyframes rotation {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
            transform: rotate(359deg);
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: So the animation is taking place in vanilla JS/html/css setup but not in your Vue.js code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safari CSS Bug: Animation Rotation Direction Incorrect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186768/safari-css-bug-animation-rotation-direction-incorrect)

Comment: Your snippet shows the animation working so can you explain a bit more about the circumstances in which it doesn't work?